# How to change icon of Sidebar Menu item in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to change the sidebar menu item, but it's not working properly. I'm trying to use `mobile` icon.

```
new MenuItem(this.l("Devices"), "", "menu", "", [
            new MenuItem(this.l("Mobile"), "Pages.Mobile", "mobile", "/app/device/mobile")
        ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free template uses [AdminBSB](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign), which [supports Material Design Icons](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/ui/icons.html).

Font Awesome's `"mobile"` is similar to Material Design's `"phone_android"`/`"phone_iphone"`.

Comment: how to check AdminBSB version in application?

Comment: You can [compare](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/compare/v1.0.4...v1.0.5) files.